# Can I select the id referenced by a link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've just created a table of contents for the list of the board of directors on the website I maintain.  Currently, I have an `<a>` tag nested inside of each `<li>` which references the place where each person's details are.  Here's what the table of contents looks like:

```
<li><a href="#1">name goes here</a></li>
```

And here's what each item on the page looks like:

```
<td id="1"> 
    <p>
        Name goes here<br>
        Details go here<br> 
    </p>
</td>
```

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish.  When you click `<a href="#1">name goes here</a>` you will be taken down to `<td id="1">`, and the background color of `<td id="1">` will change to some shade of yellow and fade back to transparent.

The movement around the page already works (it's just href to an id), and I know how to animate the background color with jquery.  What I can't figure out is how to select `<td id="1">`.  I could do it simply with

```
$('li a').click(function(){
    $('td#1').animate...
});
```

But there are 20+ items on the list, I don't want to have a separate event for each item.  Please advise.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the href attribute as an ID

```
$('li a').click(function(){
    $( $(this).attr('href') ).animate...
});
```

it's just a string and does exactly the same as writing `$('#1')` (BTW, don't use numbers as ID's)

Comment: yes calling .attr('href') will yield the id as a string. Then do what you want with that string. It would probably be easier to save that as a variable first

var myId = $(this).attr('href');

Comment: numbers are fine as ID, at least in HTML5 http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: @PeterVR - I know it's fine according to HTML5 spec, until you try using it in CSS, and it doesn't work whitout escaping and loads of shit, so generally you shouldn't use leading numers in ID's, it's just so easy to do `#a1` instead and avoid all the issues

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change your ids to characters instead of numbers, but make the href the same as the id. Then you can achieve what you want with the following:

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('li a');
for (var i = 0;i<a.length;i++) {
a[i].addEventListener('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var b = this.getAttribute('href');

    document.getElementById(b).style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: $('#'+b).offset().top},
                           'slow', function(){
                             document.getElementById(b).style.backgroundColor = 'white';
                           });




});}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nz7fd3k2/)**